# Gravity Forms Styling help descreased gap between date field and time

Tags: css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hi I am using gravity forms plugin but I am trying to have the date and time beside each other I have got this to work to an extent using the built in classes.

http://www.cambridgepuntingcompany.co.uk/bookings/

But as you see their is a big gap between the date and time which I want decreased does anybody have an idea how I would go about this